# facebook graph api /{group-id}/events doesn't list all events

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to get all events of a facebook group. via facebook graph api.
But /{group-id}/events does not return all events in the "Graph API Explorer" from developers.facebook.com.

what i found out: when i click to events in the facebook group, then there are two tabs: "Events" & "Calendar".

on the event tab, there are many events (and have also a date) 
but in the calendar of the group are not all events registered.

the graph api only list events, which are also in the calendar of the group.
/{group-id}/events

can anyone give me a tipp, how i can get all events from the group?

the relevant group is:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/unternehmenauswaldkirchen/events/

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From facebook's documentation:

> /{group-id}/events
>
> All events that **belong** to a group.

So, the reason you only see certain events in the reponse is, those are the only events that were created by the group admins and are **owned** by that group. 
The other events were created by other individuals,pages or groups, and were simply posted to your group's feed.

For example, if you look at the event scheduled for september 9:
https://www.facebook.com/events/122492428358380

You'll see that it actually belongs to this page:
https://www.facebook.com/pg/RehaundFitness

Unfortunately, the graph api offers no easy way of getting all of these events.

You have 2 options of aggregating the events on your own:

1. If the group only has a few sources that share events on it, you can request the events for each of these sources seperately, and then group the events in your code.
2. If there are multiple/unknown event sources, you can [request the group's feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/feed), find all the posts that contain `https://www.facebook.com/events/{eventId}`, and then fetch and process each of these events (Use paging to reach older posts).

Good luck!